# Ban or delay close votes from users who answered a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, etiquette, closing, deletion

Where a user has answered a question, I propose that either

> that user cannot vote to close the question

or

> the user's close vote ability is suspended on that question for one week

Conversely, a user who answers a question should be banned or delayed from casting a close vote on that question. Any earlier close vote on that question from that user should be automatically cancelled when they post the answer.

Ability to comment, request closing of the question in meta threads, and to do anything except add a close vote would not be affected.  Logically the same request applies to delete votes, but if there are subtle problems with applying it to both I am primarily talking about close votes.

There are several reasons one might want this enforced as a feature [see first revision, or some of the comments here], but I am also posting this question to invite discussion of what "social norms" might exist about the use of the close and delete votes in parallel with answers.

Comment: In theory I think this proposal makes sense. However, you have expressed it in a slightly confrontational manner, which I think is unnecessary. Yes, I think people should not be allowed to both answer a question and vote to close it (although any SE update surrounding this should be carefully implemented and will probably never happen), but I don't think that political wrangling on meta should be brought into the equation.

Comment: @user1729, feel free to suggest a more neutral phrasing, but without the illustration of how the current system can be and is used, and what the actual principle at stake is, I don't think it is quite obvious why it would be important.

Comment: It just sounds petty and parochial. You have to remember that you are proposing a Stack-Exchange wide** change in the software, but that the reasoning your proposal is based on is related to disagreements on a *meta* - it isn't even the main site! (If people voting to close whilst answering a question is actually a problem -and I have no idea if it is- gather examples from the main site.)

Comment: I would like to see examples or other indications that we would solve a problem with this restriction.

Comment: @zyx Ah, I see where you're coming from; that's entirely reasonable, I suppose. If the volume can be described as "incidentally" or "occasionally", I'd say that a simpler approach would be to ask justification from the people in question in a comment; since they've racked up enough reputation to cast close votes, it seems natural that they would be willing to explain themselves.

Comment: ...and now we are getting political...(and so I have voted to close.)

Comment: @user1729: Just don't post an answer! :-P

Comment: I am still not completely sure what I think of the general idea of the proposal, but it seems clear to me that voting to close as duplicate would need to be excluded from such it.

Comment: I think an addendum should be added to this: the answerer can opt to delete their answer and re-gain the privilege to vote to close. An exceptional case that comes to mind is if, after someone gives an answer, the asker edits the question in a way that makes it worthy of closing. Another one is that the answerer didn't realize that the question was a duplicate. Allowing the answerer to delete the answer to re-gain their close vote privileges would handle both cases nicely.

Comment: @Ataraxia Sometimes the answers to duplicate questions are better than the answers to the original. Maybe there should be a "close and merge my answer" option too?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft To be clear: I do not think that the question should be closed because it is a duplicate, but because the discussion was becoming overly political (and so "off topic"). If zyx was to re-write the question without mentioning his gripe with people on meta then I would rescind my vote to close.

Comment: @user1729 I did not mean the closing of this question. I mean that if any sort of ban on voting to close questions you have answered yourself is to be discussed, it seems clear to me that votes to close as duplicate need to be handled completely separately from other types.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh, sorry, I thought that your comment was meant as a reply to both my earlier comment and to user89499's answer (where it is pointed out that, in essence, this question is a duplicate of a very old SO proposal). Thanks for clarifying (and I agree with your point).

Comment: I've deleted a few comments.  If y'all don't quit mudslinging, there's gonna be suspensions.  *Cool off.*

Comment: I second Tobias' concern. It has happened to me a couple of times (I'm sad to say) that I have answered a question, and then my attention is drawn to the fact that the question is a dup. At that point it is the civic duty to vote to close, but I do have mixed feelings about it. Particularly if there were no other answers. Ideally I should be able to tell, whether my answer is sufficiently different from those given to the original. I have deleted my answer occasionally. Only to see that somebody else then posts yet another identical answer - before we find 5 concerned citizens to close it.

Comment: @user1729, it makes even more sense as an SE-wide change, due to the much larger number of use cases.  The meta.SO thread from four years ago has justifications that are outdated, such as answering questions that (today) would be semi-automatically migrated to meta.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I had thought about duplicates when posting, as you can see in the earlier revisions, and on consideration, I can't see a situation where the answerer's best option is to vote.  Meta has the perpetual thread for vote requests, and there are comments under the question, and flags.  On the main site these tend to be weird situations where the (original, duplicate) assignment is reversed, or such.  On meta there is a real and present possibility of users shutting down each others' questions, as you saw in the recent one where you commented. The close voter is now a delete voter.

Comment: @zyx My understanding of SE is that all the sites run on the same software, and so this can only be a SE-wide change.

Comment: @user1729, yes. I was addressing the idea that this is a case of the MSE meta tail wagging the giant SO/SE dog (and did so by reposting a comment that was inexplicably deleted).  The instances that led to this question are not limited to the meta or to MSE, and specific concerns vary between sites, such as the concern about reputation gaming in the old MSO question, which is less important outside of Stackoverflow.

Comment: I have deleted several more comments. I would like to reiterate Alexander Gruber's warning to **keep things civil**.

Comment: @user1729 Some features can be enabled for some sites but not others, for example for a long time the question limits only applied to the big 3 sites. But I would not expect any request of special features for math.SE to be well-received, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @AlexBecker Thanks, that's interesting. I (quite clearly!) didn't know that.

Comment: @AlexBecker, I can post a similar query to MSO if this is taken as a Math.SE-specific feature request, which it is not.  For now (I think that) it is of interest to learn what opinion here looks like, requests aside.

Comment: Why do so many things dissapear on this meta? Is this to encourage people to get 10k+ quickly? :-)

Comment: It is intrinsically anti-social to utilize the means of expression while seeking to deny it to others.  There are more specific uses such as reputation gaming (see the 4-year old MSO link in other answers), and any case on meta where one posts an answer (especially the only one to a question) that is largely the expression of opinions, while denying the same opportunity to others through close and delete votes.  Special pleading that "*I* am reasonable, my closing judgement could not possibly lead to a bad result, and I cannot be bothered to ask on meta" is not as compelling.

Comment: ^ the preceding comment is the response to a question in the deleted answer, asking for examples of anti-social use.  (@quid and anyone else following that discussion)  It will migrate back there in case of undeletion.

Comment: I see nothing at all objectionable in the original version of the question. The material that @user1729 described as ‘slightly confrontational’ is entirely relevant and presented in non-confrontational language. Nor do I think that it sounds ‘petty’: our first concern must surely be MSE, main and meta. Whether something is suitable for SE-wide implementation, and whether such implementation is at all likely, are separate issues.

Comment: Should we also forbid people who vote to close a question, to vote for its deletion (because that robs the ability of having the question reopened)? What about downvoting it (because that may cause an eventual deletion by the software)?

Comment: @Brian The way I read it was: "Someone asked a question about homework problems. Before this was closed someone posted an answer which I disagreed with." And so we have a meta question and a discussion that is really just the an extension of the homework question stuff. And so is overtly political. As I tried to say in my first two comments, I agree with the overall idea behind the proposal, but a single example along with hypothetical reasoning is not going to persuade the SE people that this is a genuine issue. It comes across as petty and parochial. I want to see real evidence on main!

Comment: (Or to put another slant (in my mind - the same slant) on it - we are having two discussions. One is about "freedom of speech on meta", and is fuelled by the homework debate, while the other is about people forcing their answer to be the only one, and so gaining extra rep. I believe one has to be the potential to be a genuine issue, but I have kept my eyes open for it since this question was asked and have seen no evidence (that is not to say it doesn't happen - I have done no digging). However, the other issue boils down to using meta as a political platform. Which is petty and parochial.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do not fully understand your remark. First, the issue is answer and close and I, for one, explained why I consider this as a problem with a reason and this seems to be the predominant reason that clearly does not apply directly to what you now ask. But, second, as you know there *is a software enforced delay* for deletetion for some users (earlier *all* except moderators), *precisely* to allow for reopening. And a delay is one of the suggested options in OP. So, one could even consider the current situation for deletion as supporting the suggestion in OP.  And as you (cont.)

Comment: also know, on MO for example not sure how this is here, it is considered as highly inappropriate to use deletion as a tool to interfere with potential reopening. And, moderators intervene immediately when made aware of it. So, yes, it should also be community norm that people do not vote to delete if there is a reasonable chance for the question to get reopened. Downvotes leading to deletion is also software delayed, in the sense it will only have affect for things closed since relatively long. Again, there is a delay of the effect. Quite in line with OP.

Comment: @quid Asaf used the style form called hyperbole.

Comment: @quid: The first word one sees when entering this thread is "ban". Banning something is not the same as delaying it. Moreover, freedom of speech, in one form or another, shouldn't have an expiration date. Or should it? Since it was so heavily used to convey the point of this thread, I am using it to see how slippery is the slope. I honestly want to know what the OP thinks about deletion-after-closure votes; regardless to "interfering with reopening".

Comment: @Lord_Farin but it does not seem like an exaggeration of something that seems reasonable, but it simply does not make any sense in my opinion to bring this up here. (As said, if anything what is said rather supports the stance of OP, which seems unlikely to be the actual intent in view of other contributions.) [Written before seeing Asaf Kargila's comment.]

Comment: @Asaf It seems that my stance towards the suggestions you posed made the impression that you were attempting to use hyperbole in an attempt to draw attention to facets of the proposal that you disagreed with. (Reading this again, I see that I may have been drawing more on my own thoughts rather than on your words. I will have to be more careful about making claims of someone's intentions. I hope to not have offended you.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin, no offense taken. Next time, perhaps, you might want to add "I believe", or a similar phrase to your comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for the explication. But, please note the title starts 'Ban or delay'. I think if you ask OP they might even be willing to change it to 'Delay or ban'. On your other point, I do consider it as reasonable both here an in general that after there was a reasonable possibility for everybody to express their opinion a discussion can be closed. Possibly even against the wishes of some, **but** then the decission to do this should rather not be taken by those very actively involved in the prior discussion but by more neutral observers. And this is the point of the proposal(c.)

Comment: The suggestion made in OP is quite specific; and as I said some of the things you worry about are in fact in place in one form or another; so this seems rather about closing a gap than starting something where there could be some slippery slope. As is, one would slide to *existing* things.

Comment: > *Should we also forbid people who vote to close a question, to vote for its deletion?* < ::: Maybe, but it has no logical connection to this question, except that they both deal with a sort of double-voting.  As much as I dislike closings, this proposal might actually accelerate them by causing some answerers to post close vote requests on meta.  So this has nothing to do with reducing the rate of closing.  It is about removing a loophole that users can and do exploit, to post an answer while stopping others from doing the same.  @Asaf

Comment: @user1729, what does this possibly have to do with homework or related "meta politics"?  The examples I can think of on main site and meta and other SE sites, that would have been prevented by the current proposal, did not involve homework in any way.

Comment: @zyx: You haven't answered my question. I simply asked, since there were comments about how on meta, writing an answer and quickly closing the question establishes a unique opinion, and hurts the freedom of others to express other opinions; how would voting to close and then voting to delete (as soon as possible) doesn't? It takes five users, out of which three are 20k'ers to do that within one minute.

Comment: I also have a technical concern about a loophole in this idea. Suppose that I posted an answer; but then I decided that I want to close the question, so I delete my answer and vote to close; once the question is closed I rethink it and undelete my answer. What should happen then?

Comment: @quid: I disagree with you about the idea that people who are involved in a discussion shouldn't proceed to close it. In some cases the question, or the topic, can seem perfectly reasonable. However as the discussion in the comments progresses (and I'm talking about meta here, of course, although sometimes on main), it becomes more and more apparent that the OP has an underlying agenda which may or may not be borderline dishonest. It can be even worse when that discussion is actually spread over several threads. People who don't follow everything in order, lack the context for closure. [cont.]

Comment: These things happened before, with more than one user too. And they will happen again. If you want that the people who vote to close or delete will not be actively involved in the discussion, how can you be sure that they will have the proper context for closing it? (This, if you notice, is a similar problem to flag handling on the chat system. There almost always the people who handle the flag are people not involved in the conversation, and look where it got us.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, as written in earlier comments, there is a design decision to be made, if the proposal is accepted, about whether to allow a close vote when the answer is deleted.  I think it should *not* be allowed, partly for the reason you called a technical loophole, and partly because the deleted answer is still visible to 10k+ users, and this aspect has indeed been abused on meta.

Comment: So basically you're saying: once you post an answer you can *never* vote to close it?

Comment: I'm saying that is one option, but if the general proposal is accepted it can be left to the developers or for further user discussion how to handle this choice, and while I have a personal preference, I think both outcomes are fine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think the typical meta thread here has a lot more readers, also readers that are knowledgeable about the situation, than people that leave answers. In addition, the relevance of closing on meta (as opposed to main) is anyway not so relevant in my opinion. So if you cannot find five people that agree it should be closed that did not leave an answer it should rather stay open. And, more often than not to me closings on meta do feel more like some demonstration of power (not sure if this is a good word) than actual moderation of a site. I'd prefer closing on meta is mod-only.

Comment: @AsafKaragila but as amply mentioned also users leaving an answer can *say* it should be closed. Then, others can look into the situation. If it is clear it should be closed there will be no difficulty to find the support. If there is doubt, it is better it stays open.

Comment: @quid: Since this proposal was born from a recent discussion on meta, I cannot help but find the aspects on meta to be important to it. In fact, in the comments you can still find remnants of how this proposal is mainly for the meta site. But I do agree that *a lot* of things on meta end up being shouting contests and who can tolerate the discussion the longest. Finally, the idea that only moderators can close threads on meta sounds particularly bad to me. I can't quite put my finger on why, but I'm sure they won't like that idea either.

Comment: @quid: No, that would be a very bad idea. It would change the focus of the answers from the actual topic; to arguments in favor and against closing a question. It goes, in my opinion, against the whole point of having a meta site structured as it is right now (which is far from perfect, I think). **Added:** In fact, moving closing arguments to the answers mean that the thread can become cluttered with those, instead of answers relevant to the topic -- rendering it useless, and hard to navigate, in which case the only solution is to close it...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am always hesitant to mentioned MO all the time, but I think there it worked well enough for years to have a meta *without* community moderation and rather without much moderation at all. And, you would not need to ask for closing in the answer; could  start a seperate thread or use a dedicated one. Also, re shouting contest, I read this meta since quite a bit longer than I am active on the site, this seems a bit of an exaggeration to me. A general issue is some arguments that look good to some at first glance don't withstand some scrutinity, there must be time for this.

Comment: @quid: There is a lot of difference between this community and the MO community which is inherently smaller (less inviting to non-researchers); whose occupants are mostly people which had spent quite some years in the academy (which helps people to learn how to deal with others and argue); and in general has slightly more impact on real life (the interactions with people on MO have a greater chance to come back in real life, either as invitations, collaborations, conferences; or in the lack thereof). I don't think the comparison holds water very well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes, this is why I said I am hesitant. But again I do not think the difference is that big, also I stressed that I did read *this* meta not completely but in some detail for a longer time already. And, actually, main conflicts seemed to be between people that could be or even are/were in fact also on MO, so it is not so clear how this is so different. Also, I think it is better in the long run people can express their emotions more openly rather than needing to ressort to some subtle means of 'aggression' or 'explode' at some point.

Comment: > *the topic, can seem perfectly reasonable [masking] an underlying agenda .... spread over several threads.* < /// Yes, that is EXACTLY the type of situation in which it is most important that an answerer should be blocked from voting.  The determination that there exists an abusive campaign is not something that can be relied on from somebody in the process of contesting the OP in answers.  They lack objectivity, and if the questions could not be closed with the answerer limited to making comments, answers and close requests on meta, it is very good sign the person is "overinvolved".

Comment: In other words, somebody repetitively arguing with an OP across multiple threads is likely to have worse judgement than everyone else, not better, and there is no amazing resource being lost if this "insight" has to be communicated through the slightly more complex method of posting on meta.  This is anyway the better action to take when proposing the exceptional step of treating a set of questions collectively, not each one on its own individual qualities.

Comment: And if you think an OP is raising a single campaign in $n$ postings, and do not want to ask about it on meta, a more constructive solution is to post $1$ answer in one question answering the whole campaign, and in all of the other $n-1$, post a comment linking to that answer, together with a vote to close.  This is much healthier than a protracted war on multiple fronts.

Comment: > *there were comments about how on meta, writing an answer and quickly closing the question establishes a unique opinion, and hurts the freedom of others to express other opinions* < || That is part of the problem, correct. || > *how would voting to close and then voting to delete (as soon as possible) doesn't? It takes five users, out of which three are 20k'ers to do that within one minute.* < || Of course there are similar problems with one user voting both to close and to delete. If anybody wants to propose that ban, I would happily support it, but questions about it are off-topic here.

Comment: I disagree that answering one thread, and linking it to another is a good idea. Certainly it is on paper. However when the threads are not immediately-connected (e.g. someone posting a question, and then posting a question about posting a question without a reference to the previous one), it is my experience that more than one person would feel that the secondary threads are valid concerns, and not meant for supporting a previous action via soapboxing. Voting to reopen (and to close) is very easy *before* reading the comments. But reopen votes cannot be rescinded. [...]

Comment: This means that once someone saw a thread they deemed valid after a first glance, and voted to reopen it, they cannot retract their vote. This means, amongst other things, that it will be easier to open threads which should not have been closed in the first place. The closure and/or deletion of these threads by moderators is nearly impossible after all that happened in the past year (and a half). And re-closing a thread is often harder than reopening it. This goes against the broken windows theory, which I agree with (on this context). It breeds open threads which should be closed, and deleted

Comment: And finally, the issue about deleting votes is the same issue as with the closing votes. If I feel that a post should be deleted, I will vote for its deletion, regardless to any reopening votes standing in. Not because I want to prevent its reopening, but because I think it simply doesn't deserve being on meta for one reason or another. Similarly closing a question. If I had answered a question, but I feel that the question is in any way dishonest, I have no intention of getting into personal fights over the comments with "This is a dishonest question! Vote to close!!", or worse. [...]

Comment: I prefer to take actions into my own hands, rather than urging people to close. In general, too, I feel that commenting that a question should be closed or deleted *can* be demeaning to the OP, and personally it feels *sometimes* demeaning to me as well. I prefer voting to close. So when people look at the thread, they are aware that there is a closing vote standing which signals a possible problem, and they would consider the close. (And that works, not once I voted to close *because* I saw there were standing votes, and I read the thread more closely.)

Comment: (All these arguments seem to me as they merit an answer. I will rescind my closing vote - this time - and post an answer.)

Comment: @quid and zyx: Speaking of "biased voting", do you think that in the case of a community closure/deletion the OP should have votes to reopen/undelete? After all, who's more objective than the original poster?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I would oppose any reopen/delete votes for an OP, because it would tend to place many of them in the humiliating situation of bargaining for permission to  speak, and of "legitimizing" the closing of their own questions by (nominally) involving them in the process.

Comment: Hmm. I never saw it that way. I always saw it as unfair because it's like voting for yourself in an open election. It just feels... weird.

Comment: @AsafKaragila my main arguement in favor of this proposal was not to avoid 'biased voting'. I might personally be in favor of excluding OP from voting (reopen/undelete) on their own things. But since one can vote open/close on ones own things a lot earlier (250 points) than one can vote this in general, it is explictlty built in the system that this can and should happen.

Comment: OP voting on their own things does not violate the principle of "never prevent a user from exercising option X by a chain of your own actions that includes X". So it is unrelated to the basic point of this proposal.  There might be other reasons to have this ability or not, and I did not know it exists until @quid's remark.

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be community norm that one can either answer or vote to close but **not both.**

The reason for this is quite simply that it feels inappropriate to me to use for oneself an opition (answering the question) and at the same time to do something the main or essentially sole purpose is to take this opition away for everybody (else).

To implement this into the software might have some issues to it, since as others have pointed out there can be exceptions, but as a general principle the above should be the community-norm, in my opinion. (On main and on meta.)

I think this is also something that *can* reasonably be implemented just by agreement (opposed to things for down-votes, say) since at least when/if the close-vote takes effect everybody can see who voted and thus the violation of the agreement would become visible to everybody.

If in some specific case somebody feels the need to deviate from this general principle, it would feel appropriate to me they *provide* in each such case at least a somewhat detailed *justifcation for doing this.*

Since other SE communities got mentioned, I will mention thta on MO (main, the meta in this form is so recent there was not much discussion yet) it is rather community-norm not to answer and to close. Also, the links suggest it is rather considered like so on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Proposals to this effect actually predate math.SE, they was first brought up four years ago on meta.SO: [Closing Etiquette: Why Do Some Answer *and* Close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4283) (current score +55). This *Linked* column of that thread contains several later threads on the same topic. Nothing ever came out of it. From scanning the threads, it seems that the majority expectation is that closed questions will be eventually deleted, taking the answer with them.

Perhaps this is indeed a better solution:  delete closed questions on meta (other than duplicates). I don't think that meta would lose anything valuable this way.

Comment: Actually deleting closed questions on meta *can* be problematic.

Comment: Thanks. Relying on deletion has a problem when the additional close vote from the answerer can be the decisive one. The magic number of 5 close votes or 3 delete votes might not be reached at all, or not until a much later time (during which more answers could be posted) without that person's vote.   Potentially, someone wanting to shut down a question can post a repudiating answer, vote to close, and vote to delete after it is closed.  If one or both of the votes are decisive, that seems to me like an abuse of the system, and if the votes are not decisive, there is no problem forbidding them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good feature request. I will address this in the context of the meta site first, and then in the context of the main site. (Mostly because I deem this request meta-related more than it is main-related.)

## Meta

1. **Context.** It can happen, and it has, that a user posts several threads which are linked by an invisible chain. However the discussions in the comments will often reveal this chain, to those users who actually read those discussions, which on meta can span over 60 or more comments. Sometimes each question can be seen as a reasonable question on its own in a cursory glance, and without thorough reading of the comments.

   I believe that people who are not following this context can be misled by these facts. They may vote to reopen immediately after reading the thread, without reading its comment thread (which may, or may not include links to previous questions). They may also be oblivious to a particular history that a particular user has in their method of raising topics, or logging complaints on meta.

   All this becomes very dangerous, because it can (and does, sometimes) end up with threads which shouldn't be posted in the first place, being kept open.
2. **Relevance.** In the previous, and most relevant scenario described above, it is possible that each question has a relevant question. These questions, as I remarked, can be reasonable on their own (if presented carefully), and each may merit an answer. I don't see the harm in someone who is fully aware of the context of the question posting an answer as well as a vote to close.

   In some of the cases, indeed the answer can be sometimes the explanation for the closure of the question (as well other questions within the same chain-posting).
3. **Alternatives.** In the comments to this proposal there has been several suggestions on how to handle such cases.

   1. The first was to post an answer explaining why a question should be closed. Directly. This makes no sense. If someone posts a question about A and receives an answer as to why their question should be closed, then the whole concept of Q&A system for the meta site is fundamentally flawed (which it very well may be!), and I know that I wouldn't have accepted such situation. Moreover, as a rebuttal another answer as to why the thread should be kept open (or reopened) may be posted.

      All this just contributes to cluttering the topic and derailing it further away from its purpose. In the end you have a question with answers which are not even relevant to its topic. That goes directly to undermine the philosophy of a Q&A system. And I strongly object to that.
   2. The other suggestion was to post comments requesting others to close the thread (at least in the case of a chain-post; where the solution is to answer one post and link it in the comments to the others). I find that to be demeaning and offensive. I can't see myself posting something like "This should be closed/deleted", even as a comment (not to mention as an answer like in the previous part), unless I feel that the post is extremely bad (in a case of a reopened thread, or undeleted thread, it's slightly different). And I will answer-close-delete much sooner than that.

      I don't know if I'm the only one who feels this way, but I have a very strong feeling about it. I find the idea of such comment to be insulting both to the OP and to the commenter. On the other hand, when someone starts reading a thread and they see that there are standing closing votes, they will read it slightly more critically, and consider whether or not to vote as well.

## Main

1. **Duplicates.** It can happen, and it does happen that one posts an answer before knowing it is a duplicate (in fact, it happened to me just this evening). In that case, I don't see the harm of the user voting to close. I don't feel that the user should delete their answer in that case (not to mention that the whole delete-to-regain-closing-vote is flawed and open to exploitation). I also recall once that I voted to close a question as a duplicate (I was the first voter, too), but then I decided that there is more to say on the topic. I posted an answer which I think was quite good. Certainly this cannot be an isolated situation, and I am sure that others has been in that place before.
2. **Bad questions.** It might also be the case that a user has post a relatively vague question, which when read can be understood as a particular question. Upon posting an answer, a long and tedious conversation begins in the comments with the OP, upon whoever is following it (and often it might be just the OP and the answerer) it becomes apparent that the question should be closed (because it's a crank, or otherwise). In that case, who is a better candidate to post the first closure vote than the answerer themselves?

There are probably other reasons to answer-close-delete a post, but I feel that those five a sufficient to poke some holes in the reasoning of this feature request.

Comment: Re: "They may also be oblivious to a particular history that a particular user has ... " Aren't we supposed to vote on posts, and not on users? I think this includes closevotes.

Comment: @user90090: Yes, we are. But on the meta, it might be the case (and it's not an hypothetical) that a certain user opens several threads, and some are for the sole intention of getting his previous actions "approved" by the community (even if they wouldn't be, directly). I don't see how it is possible to separate "user" from "thread" in that context.

Comment: "I also recall once that I voted to close a question as a duplicate (I was the first voter, too), but then I decided that there is more to say on the topic. I posted an answer which I think was quite good." At least this has an easy solution, as we can now retract close votes.

Comment: @Andres: It was still a duplicate. I just had more to write on the topic, and I didn't want to bump the old thread. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, sure.

Comment: "All this becomes very dangerous"?! Good to know you are around to protect us. ;-)

Comment: Now more seriosly: re Me.1 either it is relatively evident or it is not so bad. If you get in early you get one of the first comments and if a couple of people agree it will stay visible all along. If you do not get in early, it is sort of too late anyway. To shut it down half-way can cause more issues than it solves. Anyway, I fail the see the relvance of answering and closing. If somebody does not read the comment they might not read the answers either. re Me.2 once again I do not buy there are *so* few competent people around here that it is necessary for the same person to do both.

Comment: re Me 3.1: I never promoted this much but to give as a main argument against it the deviation from a Q&A style on **meta** is not very convincing. re Me 3.2: Do you find it problematic in general to leave comments explaining a vote to close one cast? I always thought this was good form. And, now, this does not directly ask for others to vote, but then indirectly ir does (of course). Also, you do not seem to have a very general problem with asking for votes in view of the fact your create a thread just to this end (true for reopen but still it is for asking for votes).

Comment: re Ma 1: From a general point of view it seems rather bad for the longterm development to have your answer in the new and not the existing question. (There might have been special circumstances but as a rule of thumb I'd say in these dup scenarios it seems better to add whatever answer to the pre-existing q.) re Ma 2: Somebody who did not get annoyed in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I downvoted the Question because I don't think it fully addresses scenarios where a User might both Answer and vote to close a Question.  This is in keeping with the sense of downvoting on Meta to indicate disagreement, rather than as a complaint about the Question's quality/scope/topic.

I assume the proposal concerns Questions on the Main site (Math.SE), so I won't try to apply the notion to Meta (other than to deny being one of the votes to close on this Question).

One scenario that I think is fully within the Community norms is where a User first votes to close a Question, either as poor quality or duplicate, but then the Question becomes clarified in Comments or edited (by OP or others) to make it acceptable.  The User then sees that they can provide a good Answer and do so.

I may have done that once myself but not recently enough for me to have a clear recollection.  However I do recall [this recent Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/466379/3111) I posted on a Question that I voted to close as Duplicate.  First I'd want you to note that I made that Answer Community Wiki to avoid an appearance of gaming the reputation system.  Second I'd want you to consider that few members were in as much of a position as I to spot the duplication, adding weight to ones responsibility to do something about it.  Third I am working on folding the new information posted there back into a revised Answer on [the original Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442043/3111), unravelling the existing literature references.

My preference would be *not* to automate a mutual exclusion of answering and voting to close, because of the complexity of accounting for cases like the above.  I'd trust in the Community's feedback and moderation processes to handle Users who abuse those opportunities for reputation gain.

Comment: In the scenario 'question is clarified',  it seems obvious to me that then one would *also* want to take back ones vote to close whether this is enforced or not. If the suggestion in OP were implemented this would happen automatically and save the manual effort. So, in this scenario it seems an improvement. Except you should be of the opinion that one might want to maintain ones vote to close in this scenario. If this should be the case I would be interested in an explication for the reason. But as said I agree that to implement this could be tricky due to exceptions.

Comment: You can take close votes back now.

Comment: @user1729 yes exactly. But also in OP it is even said explictly "Any earlier close vote on that question from that user should be automatically cancelled when they post the answer." Making very clear that the intent is not an *absolute* exclusion from answering once one voted to close, but this is only about having *both at the same time.*

Comment: @quid I was reading hardmath's answer and assuming that they didn't know you could take close votes back. If the question was edited and you have deemed that it is now OK then why wouldn't you take back your vote?

Comment: @user1729 I agree, as said in my first comment. The reason for my second comment was mainly to point out that even if one was not aware one can take back votes, just careful reading of OP would make clear that precisly this scenario is taken into account by OP. But perhaps I should not have written this as reply to you, but just as a general comment.

Comment: Ability to answer a question would be exactly the same under this proposal.  Voting to close would not block an answer, it would be cancelled by an answer.  So an answer would stop a close vote, but a vote would not stop an answer.